# Prevent video controls in Safari from triggering a click event

Tags: javascript, html, video

As can be seen in the Codepen (https://codepen.io/MrKoga/pen/PomGezw), in Safari the video controls trigger a click event on the video element. In Chrome they do not.

HTML

```
<video id="videoClick" controls width="250">
    <source src="https://example.com/media/moviewebm " type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://example.com/media/movie.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("videoClick")
  .addEventListener("click", () => console.log("video clicked"))
```

How do I to prevent this behavior in Safari? Thanks!

Comment: It seems you can not access the HTML video element's controls directly with JS so you have to confine yourself with the specific implementation of the JS engine. However you may implement your own custom controls if you want to have a custom [cross browser video player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player).

Comment: Chrome 1, Safari 0.